# Is it possible to read incoming HTTP requests in automation software like Selenium or Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer

I would like to read all incoming HTTP requests while using Selenium (or any other automation software), I would like to read the data (headers, response) from all these requests (which is just an example) when I visit a website:

[image]

Is there some way I can do that? In that case, how?

Comment: Yes, you can record all the requests with [browser mob proxy](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In puppeteer you can access request/response headers like this:

```js
page.on('request', req => {
    let headers = req.headers();
    console.log(headers);
});
page.on('response', resp => {
    let headers = resp.headers();
    console.log(headers);
});
```

For selenium, you can either use proxies such as [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) or [browsermob-proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy),
or if you're using python you can use [selenium-wire](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the [response](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#event-response) event. The `response` object has a [request](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#responserequest) property. So you should be able to get all that.

```js
const responses = new Map();
page.on('response', r => responses.set(r.url(), r));

// Load and re-load to make sure it's cached.
await page.goto('https://www.some.page.com');
```